Should the "seeking recommendations" close reason be used when the question just asks for a reference?
People often ask questions of the form "Is there a tool/library that does X?". I usually vote to close these using the "seeking recommendations" reason. But the explanation for that close reason says that it's because the responses will be opinionated. If they just want pointers, and don't ask something like "What's the best tool/library?", is it really a recommendation?
Or do we consider any answer to this to be an endorsement, hence an opinion-based recommendation?

Not opinion based but seeking off-site resources which is included in that close reason

Given that there's a specific site for software recommendations, why is this a problem?

I feel you in that it is hollow to apply that close reason as it just locks it down rather than changing it to a better situation. It's the wrong question. IMO any question which takes the form of "is there an X to do Y?" can be asked and thus also researched in a Stack Overflow compatible way. "I have X problem with restrictions A,B,C, how do I solve that?". And then an answer to such a question may well be a tool/library recommendation, but with specific instructions on how to solve the problem and not get hit by the restrictions. That is what makes the answer and thus question valuable.

@Gimby It's also valid to ask for canonical references. For example "Where can I find the documentation for X". There is no recommendation or opinion aspect involved, there is one (or at most very few) official location to find that.

I know this is closed, but a while ago, Shog opined that it's important to keep a distinction between "what is the official location of this information/content" and "can you please suggest an off-site tool or resource". Asking for a specific tool to achieve a specific task is still off-topic, but asking where Microsoft published the documentation or driver download for some task is, arguably, not, because there's no room for interpretation and there's (ostensibly) one official answer.

Ref: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/165597?m=43207688#43207688

I wish the more common response to the evergreen "Is there a tool/library that does X?" type of question was editing it to ask "How do I do X in [language/tool]?", rather than voting to close it as requesting a recommendation. If it's really "What's the best?", then close away, of course.
